# How can I make awk output more readable?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

With this code I get the students with the highest and lowest value.

But I can't find how to turn it into a more readable output.

#### Code

```
awk -F ';' 'NR==1 { min = max = $2; mina = maxa = $1 " " $2; next }
$2==max { maxa = maxa ", " $1 " " $2 }
$2==min { mina = mina ", " $1 " " $2 }
$2>max { max = $2; maxa = $1 " " $2 }
$2<min { min = $2; mina = $1 " " $2 }
END { print "Max:", maxa
  print "Min:", mina }' notas.txt
```

#### `notas.txt`

```
pepe;5
marcos;7
marta;70
luis;70
ana;5
pedro;9
paco;70
pepa;7
rosa;5
manu;8
```

#### Current output

```
Max: marta 70, luis 70, paco 70
Min: pepe 5, ana 5, rosa 5
```

#### Desired output

```
Max: 70 [marta,luis,paco]
Min:  5 [pepe,ana,rosa]
```

How could I achieve that output?

Comment: Consider choosing a standard format for your output such as CSV or JSON or XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required changes are really minor. Probably try to solve your problem yourself before asking for help.

```
awk -F ';' 'NR==1 { min = max = $2; mina = maxa = $1; next }
  { val = "," $1 }
  $2==max { maxa = maxa val }
  $2==min { mina = mina val }
  $2>max { max = $2; maxa = $1 }
  $2<min { min = $2; mina = $1 }
  END { printf "Max: %2i [%s]\n", max, maxa
    printf "Min: %2i [%s]\n", min, mina }' notas.txt
```

The format specifier `%2i` anticipates a max value with two digits; if it could go up to three digits, probably use `%3i` in both places instead.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Passing 2 times Input_file to `awk` program here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=";" }
FNR==NR{
  max=max>=$2?max:$2
  min=min && min<=$2?min:$2
  next
}
$2==max{
  maxVal=(maxVal?maxVal ", ":"") $1
}
$2==min{
  minVal=(minVal?minVal ", ":"") $1
}
END{
  print "Max: " max " ["maxVal"]" ORS "Min:" min" ["minVal"]"
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```